# If a comment appears to accept an answer, a one time dialogue should ask the user whether he wants to accept the answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, accepted-answer

A modest idea to help accepted answers be "Accepted", might be to script the comments, that if the asker says something like,

```
Thank you; that solution worked perfectly.
```

The script would check for this and similar strings, check to see if the user is "New" or has a long history of never accepting answers, and then pop up a small **one time ever** dialogue stating,

```
Did the answer provided here answer your question?
 Yes | No
```

And if he clicks yes, scroll the page up, flash the accept answer icon, and ask him to accept it, stating that it helps keep the stack exchange site clean etc~